# Windows 7 Running at 10x Speed After Fresh Installation (Very Weird)

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've been running Ubuntu for about 6 months and decided to wipe my drive and dual boot.

So I wiped the drive and popped in the Windows 7 DVD and ran it. The installation went fine but I noticed that the animations were running super fast. I shrugged it off and restarted the computer to complete the installation.

Now once I got it to the desktop, I noticed that my clock was running really fast. The minutes are literally going by as fast as seconds. Everything is running this fast. I've never seen anything like it, honestly.

I can't connect to the internet on it because of the problem (the instant I connect to a website, the connection breaks..) so I had to goto the library to ask you guys what's going on here.

Comment: Are you using the Intel Flux Capacitor CPU?

Comment: Hilarious... -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread [Windows 7 clock is running very fast](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/ccdc1365-e381-4270-b2e5-c90eb0087eea) contains several suggestions:

**A.** Switch the computer and all devices off at the wall and wait a few seconds, turn it back on, wait a few more seconds before pressing the power button.

**B.** Disabling in the BIOS the SVD (Secure virtualization mode on processors)

**C.** Update the BIOS and chipset driver (careful!)

**D.** Hardware problem with memory

**E.** To Register dll file and reset SNTP execute the following:

```
net stop w32time  
w32tm /unregister  
w32tm /register  
regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\w32time.dll  
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com,0x4 /syncfromflags:MANUAL  
net start w32time
```

If the issue still persists, reset Windows Time Service related group policy

1. Click Start, click Run, type gpedit.msc , and then click OK.
2. In the Group Policy Object Editor MMC snap-in, expand Computer Configuration, expand Administrative Templates, expand System, and then click Windows Time Service.
3. In the right pane, right-click Global Configuration Settings, and then click Properties.
4. In the Global Configuration Settings Properties dialog box, click Not Configured, and then click OK.
5. Expand Windows Time Service, click Time Providers, and then set all the objects in this node to Not Configured. To do this, follow these steps:
   a.  In the right pane, double-click Enable Windows NTP Client, click Not Configured, and then click OK.
   b.  In the right pane, double-click Configure Windows NTP Client, click Not Configured, and then click OK.
   c.  In the right pane, double-click Enable Windows NTP Server, click Not Configured, and then click OK.

If you can't start the Windows Time Service see this [thread](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaperformance/thread/6bbea43f-5575-4e78-9b52-ac766632bfc2).

Comment: Answer A worked! I was surprised! Thank you so very very much!

Comment: If this problem arrives again, it might be that your motherboard (CMOS) battery is weak.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the clock is running sped up in the BIOS window as well (hit `Del`, `F2`, `F10`, etc during bootup to enter setup).  If it is running fast there as well, the RTC (real-time clock) on the motherboard might be damaged.  Call up the manufacturer and get an RMA if it's still under warranty.

Comment: The clock speed in my BIOS is working perfectly. =/